# Split Access Database - refreshing data

Tags: ms-access-2010

Before splitting the database, i had a autoexec macro that would refresh contents of a table by the following steps: delete contents of a table, Import data from a text file and remove some certain records.  So when an user opens the database, they had the most up-to-date info.  How do i do that with a split database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: From what describe, there is nothing to change to your old procedure.

Comment: How to automate refreshing the back-end table?  I will need to add the macro to the back-end and to make sure the data is refreshed.  This would add an extra manual step.  If not the end users opening the front-end would not have up-to-date information.